# Desktop App Converter Convert Failed 'E_NO_COMPATIBLE_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE'

Tags: winapi, uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

When I use the Microsoft's [Desktop App Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) to convert a traditional Win32 app to UWP, the setup for Desktop App Converter succeeds, but when converting it encounters an error `E_NO_COMPATIBLE_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE`. The details:

```
DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_NO_COMPATIBLE_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE': No expanded base image with Windows Version compatible with the host OS could be found in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images'
所在位置 C:\Users\dhike\Desktop\DesktopAppConverter_2\converter_util\CWACLogger.ps1:141 字符: 13
+             throw New-Object -TypeName $exceptionType -ArgumentList $ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ConfigurationErrorsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_NO_COMPATIBLE_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE': No expanded base image with Windows Version compatible with the host OS could be found in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images'
```

Does anyone know the source of this error and how to fix it?

My Desktop App Converter's version is 0.1.22 and the base image is BaseImage-14383.wim, download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53122), and my host OS is Win10 Pro Preview version 1677 (14388).

Comment: Desktop App Converter is, according to Microsoft, a "pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it's commercially released."  Did you read through the [caveats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#caveats) and if so, did any apply?

Comment: yes, i ignored the caveats, but why the [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53122) said that the host os can be build 14372 and up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the base image is BaseImage-14383.wim, download from here, and my host OS is Win10 Pro Preview version 1677 (14388)
>   No expanded base image with Windows Version compatible with the host OS could be found in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images'

This exception states the converter failed to locate a base image that **matches your Insider Preview build**. Your Host OS version is Insider `14388`, the compatible Base Image version should be `14388` instead of `14383`.

So the only way is waiting for the 14388 base image and setup the converter again.

BTW: For feedback about Desktop App Converter, Centennial team is currently monitor issues on [UserVoice site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/category/161895-desktop-bridge-centennial), please post your issue there.

Comment: but on the [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53122), the System Requirements said that the host OS could be build 14372 and up

Comment: @Lomuto This page may not describe this clearly, the related team is  working on getting the base image updated to 14388.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same error. I use a Windows in the Fast Insider channel (1709 OS 16296.0). I downloaded the BaseImage "BaseImage-16257.wim"

Is this last BaseImage not correct with this Insider Build ?

```
    PowerShell Error Record:
DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_NO_COMPATIBLE_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE': No expanded base image with Windows Version compatible with the host OS could be found in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images'
PowerShell Stack Trace:
à RaiseUserException, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\DACLogger.ps1 : ligne 158
à RaiseUserException, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\DACLogger.ps1 : ligne 132
à Get-ExpandedBaseImage, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\BaseImageOps.ps1 : ligne 57
à <ScriptBlock><Process>, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 : ligne 631
à <ScriptBlock>, <Aucun fichier> : ligne 1
```